# Grab data in a string starting from the end of string to the first occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I know how to regex match from the start of a string, but am not sure how to do it from the end of string, I need to do this to detect the most recent thing a person typed in, here is an example string:

`var string = 'User id[20] EQUALS '20' AND Person Info id[30] EQUALS'`

I would want to use Regex to find the most recent id the user typed in, in this case it would be `30`

`var mostRecentID = string.replace(GRABMOSTRECENT [id] string)`

Is this possible?

Comment: @anubhava I just realized that, the `User` part of that before the `id[30]` could be any random string, I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `.replace` with a greedy `.*` match before to make sure we match only last occurrence of `id[number]`:

```
var mostRecentID = string.replace(/.*\bid\[(\d+)\].*/, '$1');
//=> 30
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LEIr8v/4)

Comment: Works amazing! Thanks